# Help With Measure Theory Proof

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm stumped on this problem and would love either a hint or a solution. Thanks in advance!!

Suppose that $E$ is measurable with $m(E)=1$. Show that there is a closed set $F$, consisting entirely of irrationals, such that $F\subseteq E$ and $m(F) = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Not really actually. The first answer doesn't seem totally correct, and the second answer uses a result from measure that has not been covered yet.